# Mixpanel with EmberJS

Tags: ember.js, transition, mixpanel

**Note:** I began writing this question, and in writing it up ended up solving the problem.  I'll leave it here and hopefully it will help someone else.

I've been pounding my head against the wall with this for a while now and keep getting inconsistent results.

**Attempt 1** (from [here](http://codebrief.com/2012/10/ember-dot-js-analytics-integration/))

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({ 
    routeChanged: function (){
        mixpanel.track("pageview", {"url": window.location.href });
    }.observes('currentPath')
});
```

I had to deviate from the example since `mixpanel.track_pageview()` is deprecated.  This resulted in incorrect location logging since I can't find a way to get what the new hash path will be once the transition rewrites the URL, and the URL hasn't been updated at this point.

**Attempt 2**

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(){
    mixpanel.track("pageview", {"url": window.location.href });
});
```

This works when the URL hash changes, but now I don't get any tracking when the site is first loaded.

Answer (score 7):

Track routing changes for a service like [Mixpanel](https://mixpanel.com/) or [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) with EmberJS reopen the router and overwrite the `didTransition` method call the mixpanel/analytics api inside the next Ember run loop.

```
Ember.Router.reopen({
  didTransition: function(paths){
    this._super(paths);
    Ember.run.next(function(){
      path = window.location.href;
      mixpanel.track("pageview", {"url": path });
    });
  }
});
```

Here is a [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/UXaLERi/1/edit?console,output)

Comment: I like this solution better than the external jQuery one.  Does this function get hit on first entry?

Answer (score 0):

**Final Solution**

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(){
    mixpanel.track("pageview", {"url": window.location.href });
});

Ember.Application.initializer({
    initialize: function(container, application) {
        mixpanel.track("pageview", {"url": window.location.href });
    }
});
```

Now I get initial page loads tracked as well as transitions within the application.