# ember-simple-auth: Any way to get session from within the Router?

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I want to use analytics tracking on every transition like mentioned in [Mixpanel with EmberJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21010093/mixpanel-with-emberjs)

In order to do so, I need to be able to reopen the `Router`.

Is there any way with `ember-simple-auth` to get the current session there? My understanding was that it's available to all the routes and controllers, but saw no mention of the Router specifically.

**EDIT**:

An alternative approach I'm exploring right now is to include a mixin on all the routes where I want to do analytics identification. I have a mixin like the following:

```
`import Ember from 'ember'`

AnalyticsMixin = Ember.Mixin.create
  beforeModel: (transition) ->
    @_super(transition)
    userId = @get('session.user_id')
    if (!Ember.isEmpty(userId))
      user = @store.find('user', userId)
      username = user.get('username') # this doesn't work
```

I can get the `user_id` from the session object, although the `Session.reopen` that I did doesn't seem to include the `user` on its own. Nor does `@store.find('user', userId)` work.

The following works fine in a template:

```
Authentication =
  name: "authentication"
  before: "simple-auth"
  initialize: (container) ->
    Session.reopen
      user: (->
        userId = @get('user_id')
        if (!Ember.isEmpty(userId))
          return container.lookup('store:main').find('user', userId)
      ).property('userId')
    container.register("authenticator:custom", CustomAuthenticator)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always get the session from Ember's container with

```
container.lookup('simple-auth-session:main');
```

Comment: In the context of the `Router` how does one get the `container`? I've only ever seen that in the context of an initializer.

Comment: Looks like probably in my case (in an `ember-cli` app) that would be `AppName.__container__.lookup('simple-auth-session:main')`.

Comment: Actually, it's possible to do with `this.container`.

Comment: Is this.container kosher?  I thought it was for ember internals only (especially/specifically via App.__container__).  Ok, I dug around and it sounds like container api is part public and in flux: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085749/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-ember-container