# Get a hold of Ember Simple Auth session via container

Tags: session, authentication, ember.js, ember-simple-auth

Following this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661352/ember-simple-auth-any-way-to-get-session-from-within-the-router), I'm trying to get the Ember Simple Auth session with `container.lookup('simple-auth-session:main');` but this gives me *undefined*.

I'm using Ember Cli and the Ember Simple Auth Devise authenticator.

Comment: is your initializer in that you're trying to get the session running after the `'simple-auth'` initializer? If not the session won't be already registered.

Comment: I'm attempting to follow [this gist](https://gist.github.com/tabolario/9861932), but I changed `after: authentication` to `after: 'simple-auth-devise'`, which I *think* is correct.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? If it's creating a `currentUser` property somehow I'd suggest you follow this Ember Simple Auth example: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/examples/4-authenticated-account.html

Comment: I just had a look at that actually. I want to get a hold of an instance of the user like mentioned in that example, but I also want to inject the user into every controller and view.

Comment: If you have a property for the user on the session object you don't need to inject the user into the controllers as well because the session is already injected and you can simply access the user via `session.user`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@marcoow's comment above worked like a charm. He pointed me to [this example](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/examples/4-authenticated-account.html)

**FIRST: add an initializer registering the custom session**

```
Ember.Application.initializer(
  name: 'authentication'
  before: 'simple-auth'
  initialize: (container, application) ->
    container.register('session:custom', App.CustomSession)
)
```

**SECOND: replace the session with your custom session**

```
window.ENV['simple-auth'] = {
  session: 'session:custom'
}
```

**THIRD: define the custom session**

```
App.CustomSession = SimpleAuth.Session.extends(
  currentUser: (->
    unless Ember.isEmpty(@user_id)
      @container.lookup('session:main').load('user', @user_id)
      //Note! I'm using Ember Persistence Foundation, therefore 'session:main', 
      //but if you're using Ember Data, use 'store:main'
  ).property('user_id')
)
```

Comment: Please note that `container.lookup('simple-auth-session:main');` will still give the default session. To look up for the custom session, you need to use `container.lookup('session:custom:main');`